# Best way to store items with parse.com

Tags: ios, database, database-design, parse-platform, storage

I'm about to begin developing on a new app, where objects (items further on) will be saved to parse.

I'm having three different item types:
1. Free
1. Normal (0.99 $)
2. Featured (1.99$)

Right now i'm saving all of the items in the same class called "items" and then fill in for the table. Let's say the item is normal:
"Free" = 0, "Normal" = 1, "Featured" = 0.

My concern is that it might take a long time for the query 'wherekey' to go through all of the items (Around 50k-100k items) just to find out that there is only 10 which is e.g normal

My question is:
"Is it best to have a single class containing all the items, or should i create 3 different classes and save the items to their respective class?"

Answer (score 1):

First of all:
 "Free" = 0, "Normal" = 1, "Featured" = 0. <-- Featured would be 3 Im right?

Theres nothing wrong with you saving the three different objects in three different classes, actually I personally think thats the best option, rather than just puting everything together in one class and make a mess.

Comment: :-) I would have gone with "2" for featured.

Comment: Actually featured would be zero. It could also be Free = NO, Normal = YES, Featured = NO. But i'm also preferring the different classes, even though i then have to have 3 queries instead of just a single one.